# I want to remap my mouse side btns to keyboards btns using Tampermonkey Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Mouse Button Remapper
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Remap mouse side buttons to keyboard buttons
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Map mouse button IDs to keyboard key codes
    const buttonMappings = {
        3: 'P', // Change this to the desired key code
        4: 'O' // Change this to the desired key code
        // Add more mappings as needed
    };

    // Add event listener for mouse button press
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        const buttonId = event.button;
        if (buttonMappings[buttonId]) {
            // Simulate keydown event for the mapped key
            const keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': buttonMappings[buttonId]});
            document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
        }
    });

    // Add event listener for mouse button release
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
        const buttonId = event.button;
        if (buttonMappings[buttonId]) {
            // Simulate keyup event for the mapped key
            const keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'key': buttonMappings[buttonId]});
            document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
        }
    });
})();
```

I dont know any other ways to solve this.
suggest anything please.
I dont know chromes code.

Comment: It might be easier to use e.g. AutoHotkey for this.